# Covnert JSON to string in android

Tags: android, json, email

I am trying to get the user details using [people.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.get?userId=me) in which I have emails which I need to get that value.

This is what I mean:

[image]

This is how I'm trying to do but unable to get the value

```
try {
            String resp =profile.getEmails().toString();
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(resp);
            JSONObject uniObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("emails");
            String  email = uniObject.getString("value");
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtemail)).setText(email);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you show what resp string contains?

Comment: It contains the value and type which are displayed above

Comment: Its displaying for me as [value:"xyz@gmail.com,type:"account"]

Comment: [] means it is a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON response, `emails` is a `JSONArray`, not a `JSONObject`. You would need to get it like this:

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(responseString);  //your response
try {
    JSONArray responseArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("email");
    for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
        // get value with the NODE key
        JSONObject obj = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String lastName =  obj.getString("value");
        String firstName =  obj.getString("type");
        EmailResponse myResp = new EmailResponse();
        myResp.setValue(value);
        myResp.setType(type);
        //set all other Strings
        //lastly add this object to ArrayList<MyResponse> So you can access all data after saving
    }

} 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

POJO Class:

```
public class EmailResponse{
    public String value = "";
    public String type = "";
    //getter setters
}
```

Hope this helps.